# laravel eager loading use parents column value inside nested relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

Here is my scenario, I have 2 table `Orders` and `Employees`. They have many to many relationship, so there is a pivot table to connect them. `Order` table has a few fields such as `date`,`in_time`,`oute_time` etc.

Now I want to get all the employees for orders within a current week. I can do that easily with

```
$orders = Order::with(['employees'])
               ->currentWeek($fromDate, $tillDate)
               ->get()
               ->groupBy('date');
```

Here `currentWeek` is a `scope` where date range is calculated. What I need to do is have a nested relation with employees having all the `orders` on the same date, like

```
$orders = Order::with(['employees' => function ($q) {
            $q->with(['orders' => function ($q) {
                $q->where('child_order.date', '=', 'parent_order.date');
            }]);
          }])->currentWeek($fromDate, $tillDate)->get()->groupBy('date');
```

How do I access `parent orders columns` inside the nested?

Example:
`Order` table has 2 fields, `in_time` and `out_time`. My purpose is to list all **orders** within a week and get all employees which has been added to an **order**. At the same time, I need to determine if an **employee** is added to an **order** whose **in_time/out_time** conflicts. Like, I have an **order** on **dec-22** which starts at **3-30pm** and ends at **9-30pm**. Now, I need to list all employees for that order and list all the **orders** for each employees which matches the **date** and falls within the `**in_time/out_time**

Comment: I didn't get your question, why are you again fetching `orders` from `employees`, as you're already getting the `employees` from `orders`?

Comment: Like an `order` on `dec-22` has `5 employees`. Now I want to get all the `orders` those 5 `employees` have on `dec-22`.

Answer (score 0):

This might not give you the exact answer your looking for, but have you tried approaching the problem using the Employee model? If you were to use the employee's model and its orders relationship, you could just query that. Like so

```
$orders = Employee::with('orders')
    ->whereHas(['orders' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('date', '<', $tillDate);
        $q->where('date', '>', $fromDate);
    })->get();
```

This would also mean you need to have a hasMany relationship on the Employees model like so

Employee model

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

Given your scenario you described in the comments, this would give you a collection with the 5 employees, and any orders they have made in between the dates.

Comment: `Order` table has 2 fields, `in_time` and `out_time`. My purpose is to list all `orders` within a week and get all employees which has been added to an `order`. At the same time, I need to determine if an `employee` is added to an `order` whose `in_time/out_time` conflicts. Like, I have an `order` on `dec-22` which starts at `3-30pm` and ends at `9-30pm`. Now, I need to list all employees for that order and list all the `orders` for that employee which matches the `date` and falls within the `in_time/out_time`